# What is the most efficient way to convert this jekyll code to PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, jekyll

What is the most efficient way to convert this jekyll code to PHP?

```
{% for post in site.posts limit: 12 %}
    <a href="{{post.url}}" style="background-image: url(assets/img/posts/thumbnails/{{post.thumbnail}})" class="academic-thumb">
        <div class="academic-meta">
            <div class="name">
                {{post.title}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: jekyll is written in ruby.. so the question would be how can i convert ruby to php? so study the ruby syntax first and the the php one...

Comment: Jekyll is written in ruby, but this isn't ruby: this is liquid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  foreach ($site->getPosts() as $post) {
    echo '
      <a href="'. $post->getUrl() .'" style="background-image: url(assets/img/posts/thumbnails/'. $post->getThumbnail() .')" class="academic-thumb">
    <div class="academic-meta">
        <div class="name">
            '. $post->getTitle() .'
        </div>
    </div>
        </a>';
  }
```

This is will of course only work if the $post object is available and has gathers for the variables.

You should also listen to @borracciaBlu: study the ruby syntax first and the the php syntax